# golang operator % not defined on float64

Tags: go

There's a leetcode test [326. Power of Three](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-three/) with a Mathematics method with java:

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isPowerOfThree(int n) {
        return (Math.log(n) / Math.log(3) + epsilon) % 1 <= 2 * epsilon;
    }
}
```

When I intend to convert this solution to Golang Like

```
import "math"

func isPowerOfThree(n int) bool {
    return (math.Log10(float64(n)) / math.Log10(3)) % 1 == 0.0 
}
```

then here comes the compile error like

```
Line 4: Char 53: invalid operation: math.Log10(float64(n)) / math.Log10(3) % 1 (operator % not defined on float64) (solution.go)
```

I check the math package but there's no supported function like `%` operator, Is there any valid operator like `%` in Golang? thanks a lot :)

Comment: [How hard did you look?](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Mod) Maybe also think about why it's performing `% 1` and see if it's still needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TLDR:  `_, frac := math.Modf(f)`

You could use [`func Mod(x, y float64) float64`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Mod) in `math` package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "math"
)

func isPowerOfThree(n int) bool {
    return math.Mod((math.Log10(float64(n)) / math.Log10(3)), 1.0) == 0.0 
}
```

You could also use [`func Modf(f float64) (int float64, frac float64)`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Modf).

```golang
package main

import (
    "math"
)

func isPowerOfThree(n int) bool {
    _, frac := math.Modf((math.Log10(float64(n)) / math.Log10(3)))
    return frac == 0.0
}
```

Comment: Only this solution won't work as frac is not limited to single decimal point. As a further solution we need to check                                              
```
func isPowerOfThree(n int) bool {
    quo,_ := math.Modf((math.Log10(float64(n)) / math.Log10(3)))
    return n == int(math.Pow(3, quo))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not use just below function, as there can be more than one digit after decimal in `frac`

```
_, frac := math.Modf((math.Log10(float64(n)) / math.Log10(3)))
return frac == 0.0
```

So to resolve this, use below logic

```
func isPowerOfThree(n int) bool { 
   quo,_ := math.Modf((math.Log10(float64(n)) / math.Log10(3))) 
   return n == int(math.Pow(3, quo)) 
}
```